# What is the difference between Call Stack and Stack Trace?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, stack-trace, callstack

What is the difference between the terms "Call Stack" and "Stack Trace" ?

Comment: Can't say I haven't wondered this myself

Comment: About 3 letters? </tongueincheek>

Answer (score 53, accepted):

A call stack is typically "the current stack of operations" - i.e. while it's running.

A stack trace is typically a copy of the call stack which is logged at some sort of failure, e.g. an exception.

In other words, while you're debugging you will look at the current call stack - but when you look at logs, you'll get a stack trace. At least, that's my interpretation of the terms :)

Comment: I view it as the stack trace is like the result (trying to think of a better word) of your progress along the call stack? Or is that wrong?

Comment: @AndyC: I'm not sure I understand what "progress along the call stack" means.

Comment: Hmm, I'm potentially wrong then (either that or I'm really bad at explaining :) ). Sort of like if the call stack is the route you're going to take through the application then the stack trace shows you how you've done so far?

Comment: @Jon : So if I say: " Call Stack refers to an ongoing process whereas 'stack trace' refers to a log of a failed process " am I correct?

Comment: @pencilCake: Well, you can get a stack trace without it *always* being a failure - and even if there's a failure, it may be more localized than the whole process failing - but that's along the right lines, I think.

Comment: Yes! pencilCake is saying what I am trying and failing to say, sort of. :) Thanks pencilcase + Jon.

Comment: Can we say that stack trace shows info about where the error occurred and uptill the code where exception handling is placed. Where as call stack shows everything from the first function that called the code uptill the currently running function.

Comment: @variable: I don't think I understand your distinction clearly enough. Generally it doesn't matter where an exception is handled - the stack trace of the exception is usually captured at the point when it's thrown.

Comment: Python example - When an exception occurs, the stack trace `traceback.format_exc()`will show everything from the point where error occurred Up till the place where it is handled. Where as irrespective of an exception occurring, when we invoke the call stack `traceback.format_stack()` - This shows the reverse - that is - from start of program to the format_stack call

Comment: @variable: I still don't really understand what you mean, but I don't think it's terribly relevant to this particular question given that the question has the .NET tag.

Answer (score 22):

I think Wikipedia does a fairly good job at distinguishing between them:

> a call stack is a stack data structure that stores information about the active subroutines of a computer program
>
> A stack trace is a report of the active stack frames at a certain point in time during the execution of a program.

In other words, the call stack is the actual data structure in memory, while the stack trace is a snapshot of said data structure.

Answer (score 13):

Call stack is a data structure storing information about active subroutines in a running program.
Stack trace is a representation of the call stack.

Answer (score -1):

**Call Stack** is the raw executed code you see in the file.
**Stack Trace** is the code that you see in the console.
Simple as such.